# An object or column name is missing or empty.empty alias names

Tags: sql-server

why this error??

```
SELECT ( CASE
           WHEN BalanceTransfer.mobile_operator_desc = 'Paypoint'
                AND money_transfer.MoneyTransfer = 'NCELL' THEN 'Paypoint'
           WHEN BalanceTransfer.mobile_operator_desc = 'Paypoint'
                AND money_transfer.MoneyTransfer = 'UTLP' THEN 'Paypointutl'
           WHEN BalanceTransfer.mobile_operator_desc = 'Paypoint'
                AND money_transfer.MoneyTransfer = 'SIMTV' THEN 'Paypointsimtv'
           ELSE BalanceTransfer.mobile_operator_desc
         END ),
       ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DT_date, 101), '''') Txndate,
       COUNT(*)                                     txn,
       reseller_agent.reseller_id,
       reseller_agent.userName,
       SUM(ISNULL(selling_price, 0.00))             amount,
       SUM(ISNULL(amount, 0.00))                    facevalue
INTO   #tempRoutewise
FROM   BalanceTransfer WITH ( NOLOCK )
       JOIN dbo.money_transfer WITH (NOLOCK)
         ON BalanceTransfer.mobile_operator = money_transfer.Mobile_Operator
       LEFT OUTER JOIN reseller_agent WITH ( NOLOCK )
                    ON BalanceTransfer.Branch_Id = reseller_agent.reseller_id
WHERE  1 = 1
       AND Status <> 'confirming'
       AND BalanceTransfer.mobile_operator IN( 1, 2, 6, 14, 15 )
       AND ISNULL(money_transfer.IsUtility, 'n') = 'y'
       AND money_transfer.Mobile_Operator IS NOT NULL
GROUP  BY BalanceTransfer.mobile_operator_desc,
          money_transfer.MoneyTransfer,
          reseller_agent.reseller_id,
          reseller_agent.userName,
          ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DT_date, 101), '''')

SELECT *
FROM   #tempRoutewise
```

Comment: What is the name of the first column returned by your query?

Answer (score 0):

As Martin points out in his comment, your first column doesn't have a name. You are trying to create a table. Obviously all columns in that table have to have a name, and the name is the name of the column you select. If you try:

```
SELECT  CASE
           WHEN BalanceTransfer.mobile_operator_desc = 'Paypoint'
                AND money_transfer.MoneyTransfer = 'NCELL' THEN 'Paypoint'
           WHEN BalanceTransfer.mobile_operator_desc = 'Paypoint'
                AND money_transfer.MoneyTransfer = 'UTLP' THEN 'Paypointutl'
           WHEN BalanceTransfer.mobile_operator_desc = 'Paypoint'
                AND money_transfer.MoneyTransfer = 'SIMTV' THEN 'Paypointsimtv'
           ELSE BalanceTransfer.mobile_operator_desc
         END AS mobile_operator_desc ,
       ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DT_date, 101), '''') Txndate,
       COUNT(*)                                     txn,
       reseller_agent.reseller_id,
       reseller_agent.userName,
       SUM(ISNULL(selling_price, 0.00))             amount,
       SUM(ISNULL(amount, 0.00))                    facevalue
```

It should work.